# Mangopay error when registering card

Tags: javascript, payment

I am using mangopay for payments on my web app. I use the mangopay js kitt for card registration https://github.com/MangoPay/cardregistration-js-kit.
When The user is on my payment page and clicks on the payment button and it triggers the registerCardDemo() function. This function gets the card's data and 'inits' the cardRegistration process :

```
function registerCardDemo() {
      if ($('#js-CGV').prop('checked')) {
        $('#js-error-cgv').addClass('hide');

        var resultDiv         = $("#js-result");
        resultDiv.removeClass('alert-danger').addClass('alert-warning').html("Vérification…");
        resultDiv.removeClass('hide');

        // Card register data prepared on the server
        var cardRegisterData = {
          cardRegistrationURL:  "<%= @card['CardRegistrationURL'] %>",
          preregistrationData:  "<%= @card['PreregistrationData'] %>",
          accessKey:            "<%= @card['AccessKey'] %>",
          Id:                   "<%= @card['Id'] %>"
        }

        // Card data collected from the user
        var cardData = {
          cardNumber:         $("#card_number").val(),
          cardExpirationDate: $("#card_expiration_date").val().replace('/',''),
          cardCvx:            $("#card_cvx").val(),
          cardType:           $("#card_type").val()
        }

        // Set MangoPay API base URL and Client ID
        mangoPay.cardRegistration.baseURL   = "<%= ENV['MANGOPAY_API_URL'] %>";
        mangoPay.cardRegistration.clientId  = "<%= ENV['MANGOPAY_CLIENT_ID'] %>";
        var validateCard = mangoPay.cardRegistration._validateCardData(cardData)

       if (validateCard == true) {
          console.log("les datas de la carte sont bonnes");
        // Initialize the CardRegistration Kit
          mangoPay.cardRegistration.init(cardRegisterData);

          // Register card
          mangoPay.cardRegistration.registerCard(cardData,
            function(res) {
              var message = '<strong>Votre carte a été vérifiée ' + res.CardId + ' </strong>.<br />';
              message    += '<strong>Le paiement est en cours</strong>';
              resultDiv.removeClass().addClass('alert alert-success');
              resultDiv.innerHTML   = message;

              var form = $('#payment_form');
              form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);
              form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="card_id" />').val(res.CardId));
              form.get(0).submit();
            },
            function(res) {
              var message = "<strong>Votre carte n’a pas été débitée.</strong><br />";
              message    += '<strong>' +res.ResultMessage + '<br /> Code : ' + res.ResultCode + '</strong>' ;

              resultDiv.addClass('alert alert-warning');
              resultDiv.innerHTML   = message;
            }
          );
        }
        else {
           console.log("les datas de la carte sont mauvaises");
          $("#js-result").removeClass("alert-warning").addClass('alert-danger');
          $("#js-result").html("<strong>Les informations de votre carte sont incorrectes. Merci de bien vouloir réessayer avec une autre carte. </strong>") ;

        }

      }
      else {
        $('#js-error-cgv').removeClass('hide');
      }
    }
  </script>
<% end %>
```

I am getting the following error in the console when trying to register the card

```
mangoPay.cardRegistration.registerCard

POST https://homologation-webpayment.payline.com/webpayment/getToken net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
```

the console is showing me error on line 510 of

https://github.com/Mangopay/cardregistration-js-kit/blob/master/kit/mangopay-kit.js#L510
when trying to tokenizeCard :
https://github.com/Mangopay/cardregistration-js-kit/blob/master/kit/mangopay-kit.js#L107

What am I missing here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like it was a known issue which has since been resolved: https://github.com/Mangopay/mangopay/issues/8